# Do public static final class variables exist

Tags: php

In Jave you can define a `public static final` variable in a class. Is there an equivalent to this in PHP?

I'd like to do the following:

```
<?php

class MyClass{

    public final static $finalVariable = "something";
}

MyClass::$finalVariable
```

and not ever have to worry about `$finalVariable` changing and not having a new instance for every instantiation of `MyClass`

Comment: A *variable* is *variable*. Are you looking for a *constant*?

Comment: @deceze - no, final means it can't be overriden in childs, but can be changed (unlike constant)

Comment: Read here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494381/static-classes-in-php-via-abstract-keyword

Comment: replace 'public final static' with 'const', and you are good to go.

Comment: @Alma Sure, but the OP said "not ever have to worry about [it] changing". A *variable* can be changed. If he's accessing a static property using `Class::$property`, he never has to worry about *sub classes* because he's explicitly accessing `Class`.

Comment: this can be implemented as `protected`/`private` field w/ getter w/o setter...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

From [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php) in the PHP manual:

> Note: Properties cannot be declared final, only classes and methods may be declared as final.

However, you can use **class constants** as described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php).

Your example would look something like this:

```
<?php

class MyClass{
    const finalVariable = "something";
}

MyClass::finalVariable;
?>
```

Except of course that `finalVariable` isn't really an appropriate name because it's not variable =).

Comment: This also doesn't prevent subclasses from overriding it, as one might expect for "final". You can still create a subclass that says "const finalVariable = 99;" and in instances of the subclass it will be 99.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as `final` or `readonly` keywords/concepts for member variables in PHP OOP. [`final`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php) itself is available for classes themselves and functions contained within only.

What you should consider using instead is a [class constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php), this will guarantee that the value can not change.

```
class MyClass
{
    const FINALVARIABLE = "something";
}

// Usage
MyClass::FINALVARIABLE
```

Comment: There is a `final` keyword in PHP (as of PHP5), but is only applies to methods, not variables.

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm Yep thanks, was just updating my answer with that needed to get the wording right :)